Do coherent sheaves on compact Kähler manifolds admit locally free resolution?
Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold, and $F$ a coherent sheaf. Does $F$ admit a locally free resolution
$$E^* \to F \to 0?$$
Of course it will be enough to construct a surjection
$$E^0 \to F \to 0$$
for a locally free sheaf $E^0$.
I know that if $X$ is projective, this can be obtained by twisting with an ample line bundle to obtain a surjection
$$H^0(F \otimes \mathcal O(n)) \otimes \mathcal O_X \to F \otimes \mathcal O(n) \to 0.$$
According to Appendix B of Fulton's Intersection Theory, this statement still holds more generally for smooth schemes $X$. But what if $X$ is not algebraic?

For a finite length resolution $ E^{\bullet} $, this is false by a theorem of Voisin, that any holomorphic vector bundle on a general torus of dimension > 2 has vanishing Chern classes $ c_i $ for every $ i > 0 $. Then a finite length resolution of the ideal sheaf of a point on such a torus does not exist, due to the Whitney formula.
The reference is Voisin’s Survey specifically, Theorem 13 and the ensuing discussion.

Interesting, thanks for the reference! If I'm not mistaken, Serre's criterion for regular local rings (homological dimension is finite) the implies there are no infinite free resolutions.
